# Is it possible to find out in which table the record is not present using Explain Plan or SQL trace

Tags: sql-server, db2, sql-execution-plan

I have a query with combination of multiple tables. For example: query contains 7 or 8 tables. My query is not fetching any records.

Is it possible to find out in which table the record is not present using **Explain Plan or SQL Trace** in Db2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server the actual execution plans contains the actual number of rows. See [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Also the arrows between operators contain the number of rows exchanged by the two operators involved. A knowledgeable expert can properly interpret the information in the execution plan to understand which join(s) is(are) suppressing the output.

For non-expert users is usually much easier to just look at the individual tables and figure out why the join has 0 rows.